# How to specify in an XML schema that either one of two fields must be present?

Tags: xsd

I want to specify that either `fieldname` or `freetext` must always be present in XML files that apply to this XSD. Is there a way to do that?

```
<xs:complexType name="tSome">
<xs:sequence>
  <!-- either one of the two below has to be present. -->
  <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="freetext" type="xs:string" />
  <!-- this one below must always be present -->
  <xs:element name="dbtablename" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: i'm really sorry, but the previous minOccurs-tags where there only because my implementation of choice was that fieldname and freetext were just optional.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is a [Choice Indicator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp) in XML Schema, which allows you to take one of the contained elements, but not two or more. If you want any 2 of 3, I suggest doing something like this:

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="freetext" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="dbtablename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:choice>
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="freetext" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
  <xs:element name="dbtablename" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
</xs:choice>
```

(Maybe `maxOccurs` will prevent you from choosing one and the same element twice.)
If that does not work, nothing will I think.

**Edited**: I didn't correctly understand the question the first time. If you want `dbtablename` to always be present with any one of `fieldname` or `freetext`, then this is the answer:

```
<xs:complexType name="tSome">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="freetext" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="dbtablename" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! have to try l8r how the minoccurs and maxoccurs work with choice. i accept the answer later if it works although your example was not what i needed. cheers!

Comment: sorry: weekend happened: either fieldname or freetext and not both. dbtablename always. see my edited original question (why minOccurs tags were there). My question now is: is it now really 'either fieldname or freetext and not both' since it has minOccurs tags. That is again my mistake in orig. question but ain't you think they should be removed?

Comment: @matti They can be removed, as minOccures="0" does not do anything.

Comment: @matti Instead you can add maxOccures="1", if you don't want elements to be specified twice or more times.

Comment: @draco: 'minOccures="0" does not do anything' you mean in this choice-case? because normally it means that xml-file  does not have to specify that tag.

edit: actually minOccurs="0" should mean something because the default in choice is min=1 & max=1

Comment: @draco: 'Instead you can add maxOccures="1", if you don't want elements to be specified twice or more times' what do you mean? maxOccurs=1 is the default always and means that in xml file tag/element can be there max once. in case of choice default is minOccurs="0" and maxOccurs="0".

Comment: @matti Ok, sorry for confusing you. So if you want exactly 1 of dbtablename, and 1 of other two, you need not specify anything more.

Answer (score 6):

So, you want either `fieldname` or `freetext` and not both? or maybe both? and then `dbtablename` optionally?

Here is 1 or 2 of the elements:

```
<xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2">
    <xs:element name="fieldname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="freetext" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="dbtablename" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:choice>
```

Is this what you want? or did you want `dbtablename` to be separate?

Comment: sorry: weekend happened: either fieldname or freetext. dbtablename always.  the problem with choice is that xsd.exe generates weird code for it.

Comment: what minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2" mean here?

Comment: Well, min/max on the choice means that you want either 1 or 2 of the elements. That isn't what you want and Draco's answer is closer to what you wanted. Most xsd compilers generate some strange code for choices. I use Jax-b 2 and it is acceptable to me.

Comment: thanks anyway! Jax-b 2  is for Java and I need C# class generator. Have to try WSCF (for WSDL->Classes) since it has .xsd generation option also.

Comment: @JeffWalker Do the minOccurs/maxOccurs attributes work that way? I am under the impression they may apply to the chosen element, not the number of elements from the choice set allowed. (Based on the definition from W3: 
`XML Schema choice element allows only one of the elements contained in the <choice> declaration to be present within the containing element.`
([http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_choice.asp])
)