# Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'person' is not comple te. One of '{staff}' is expected

Tags: xml, xsd, runtime-error, xslt-1.0

Persons will the root tag. Persons will have the entry of each person with name, age, gender, address. A person can be either a student or staff. student will have rollno, standard and section. If staff, then staffid and subject. Every student must have an address with the following entry- doorno,street,city and state.
The admin has come up with an XML document.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<persons>
    <person>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <age>11</age>
        <gender>M</gender>
        <address>
            <doorno>27</doorno>
            <street>Tony's road, koramangala</street>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <state>Karnataka</state>
        </address>
        <student>
            <rollno>10</rollno>
            <standard>6</standard>
            <section>A</section>
        </student>  
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Shiny</name>
        <age>12</age>
        <gender>F</gender>
        <address>
            <doorno>10</doorno>
            <street>Main Bazar, Madiwala</street>
            <city>Bangalore</city>
            <state>Karnataka</state>
        </address>
        <staff>
            <staffid>123</staffid>
            <subject>Maths</subject>
        </staff>
    </person>
</persons>
```

and my XSD :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="persons">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="person" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="address">
                        <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="doorno" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>



                    <xs:element name="student">
                        <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="rollno" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="standard" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="section" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                    <xs:element name="staff">
                        <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="staffid" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>

                </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Iam new to XML and a learner.

The error:

```
Exception: cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'person' is not comple te. One of '{staff}' is expected.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD says that there should be `<xs:element name="student">` followed by `<xs:element name="staff">`, but instead you would like to have "either a student or staff". For this XSD has another element, `<xs:choice>`:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="student">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="rollno" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="standard" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="section" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="staff">
        <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="staffid" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:choice>
```

Please also check out another answer: [How to specify in an XML schema that either one of two fields must be present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523750/how-to-specify-in-an-xml-schema-that-either-one-of-two-fields-must-be-present)